# Suppress global ajax in kendo autocomplete MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I have a kendo autocomplete box, which is bound to remote data.
whenever i type into the search box, my default Ajax loading  animation is pop outs

i did some googling and found-->>> [***this***](http://www.telerik.com/forums/suppress-global-ajaxstart-ajaxcomplete-when-using-combobox-autocomplete)
which says to include `global: false` in read to suppress this global ajax behavior

how can this be done in MVC wrapper?

```
     @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
   .Name("productAutoComplete") 
   .DataTextField("ProductName") 
   .DataSource(source =>
    {
       source.Read(read =>
       {
            read.Action("GetProducts", "Home"); 
       })
       .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same scenario. After searching the internet for hours only answer on my hand was "You can't do it with wrappers. You have to initiate the autocomplete by js." But then I saw another solution for another product which make sense.

Here's what I did for my project:

In main js file;

```
var ajaxStartActive = true;
$(document).ajaxStart(
    function () {
        if (ajaxStartActive)
            $loading.show();
    }).ajaxStop(
    function () {
        $loading.hide();
    });
```

Using with AutoComplete;

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
   .Name("productAutoComplete")
   .HtmlAttributes(new { onfocus = "ajaxStartActive = false;", onblur = "ajaxStartActive = true;" }) 
   .DataTextField("ProductName") 
   .DataSource(source =>
    {
       source.Read(read =>
       {
            read.Action("GetProducts", "Home"); 
       })
       .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
 )
```

I hope it helps